# qt open a jpg file with warning image format not supported

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

[image: screenshot of error]

I open a file of format "jpg" in qt creator ,but qt creator returns a warning with "image format not supported". I also try other format as "png" ,but the waring is same.I hope someone can give me advice on it.I really need help.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: @eyllanesc This question has to do with Qt Creator IDE. The code is not relevant.

Comment: What version of Qt Creator are you using, and how did you obtain it (online download, self-built, etc.).

Comment: Actually your image has conversion problem using any photo editor.. So you have to convert jpg or png format again and do the repeated steps.. It will supports perfectly i think..

Comment: I have tried and it appeared the problem I described below , it seems strange and hope your help.

Answer (score 2):

This Warning is about PNG formats and Qt, Irrelevant to @ztono code.
Read more about PNG (Portable Network Graphics) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

PNG has many Formats some old, some not standard for Qt. see more [History_and_development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#History_and_development)
You need to use Standard format in Qt.

You can convert your image to PNG Standard with Software.

OR

You can use QImage in Qt to convert your PNG pictures.

```
QImage *image = new QImage();
image->load("E:/Qt/TestProject/Images/connect.png");
image->save("E:/Qt/TestProject/Images/connect2.png");
```

Use new converted png and you will not see the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem . It was because i had already moved the png file in my projects folder. But i tried to add image by clicking add new where i should have clicked add existing.