# loop over a list of urls using PyQt4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pyqt4

I am trying to loop over a list of URLs using PyQt4 and Beautifulsoup using the following code:

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl, pyqtSignal
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage

class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, urls, cb):
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.urls = urls  
    self.cb = cb
    self.crawl()  
    self.app.exec_()  

  def crawl(self):  
    if self.urls:  
      url = self.urls.pop(0)  
      print ('Downloading', url)  
      self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    else:  
      self.app.quit()  

  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    frame = self.mainFrame()  
    url = str(frame.url().toString())  
    html = frame.toHtml()  
    self.cb(url, html)
    self.crawl()  

def scrape(url, html):
    pass
    soup = BeautifulSoup(unicode(html), "lxml")   
    t  = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "detalhamento_label_valor hidden-print ng-binding"})[0].text
    print t

urls = ["http://apps.mpf.mp.br/aptusmpf/index2#/detalhe/920000000000000000005?modulo=0&sistema=portal" ,
        "http://apps.mpf.mp.br/aptusmpf/index2#/detalhe/920000000000000000005?modulo=0&sistema=portal" ,
        "http://apps.mpf.mp.br/aptusmpf/index2#/detalhe/920000000000000000004?modulo=0&sistema=portal" ]

r = Render(urls, cb=scrape)
```

It seems to work well if the urls are the same `[0,1]`, but it gets stuck once the url changes `[2]`. I am not really familiar with PyQt4, so I wonder if there is something trivial I might be missing.

**EDIT**

The program hangs while running the third item of the url list on this operation:

```
self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
```

Other than that, the only warning I get is:

> libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile

Though I'm not sure what it means, it does not seem to be connected to the issue.

Comment: When you say, "It seems to work well if the urls are the same [0,1]" do you mean that it does `print t` two times ? What do you actually mean ?

Comment: Yes, it prints the values corresponding to the first two urls. But the code crashes when it reaches the third url.

Comment: @tan then please include the traceback, so we can see the error.

Comment: possibly related: [qt open a jpg file with warning image format not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374187/qt-open-a-jpg-file-with-warning-image-format-not-supported)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745076/libpng-warning-iccp-known-incorrect-srgb-profile)